# Ruby on Rails - How to properly separate controllers/views in MVC framework

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, architecture

I'm putting together a quick virtual craps game as a learning project, and am a little lost on the best way to organize everything.

The game is really simple. There are 4 "states" to the game. A welcome screen, first roll that sets your "goal", a rolling state where you can win/lose as you keep rolling for your goal, and a win/lose state.

What I was going to do was have 2 controllers. One for start the game that displays the rules and a button to start the game and one to control the logic of rolling the dice. The start game controller will initialize all values and basically reset the game and the rolling the dice controller handles the game play.

Now, where I'm tripped up is on the views. I have 1 view for the start game controller, and then for the rolling the dice controller I have 4 views. One view to display your first roll and the output for your goal, one to display each successive roll, one for a win, and one for a loss.

Is this correct, or should I just have one view for controller and have a switch statement that chooses which output to display? I think multiple views is a little cleaner, but it also makes me repeat one chunk of code a few times to display the header and images per roll.

Which way is correct? Thanks!

Comment: You can go with different views/actions and to keep your code clean and DRY, you can use `partials`. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would fit with a "home" controller to display the rules and a game controller to manage the game logic. Just as you said, create a welcome view for the home controller and a first roll view, a rolling view and a game over view for the game controller.